# Qt OpenGL ES 2.0 - unable to draw a rectangle

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I googled a lot, without an answer to my problem. I'm learning OpenGL and I'm making little programs with Qt because I want to use a Raspberry PI 2.

I'm struggling with a simple program: the drawing of a rectangle (4 vertices with index) and a texture. As I said, I'm using Qt, hence a subclass of QOpenGLWidget.

When I compile this program for desktop, it works perfectly. In this case I guess Qt uses OpenGL. When I switch on ARM I guess Qt compile using OpenGL ES 2.0.
And I don't see the rectagle. Where I wrong? I'm going crazy.

Header file;

```
 #ifndef MYGLWIDGET_H
 #define MYGLWIDGET_H

    #include <QOpenGLWidget>
    #include <QOpenGLFunctions>
    #include <QOpenGLBuffer>
    #include <QOpenGLShader>
    #include <QOpenGLTexture>

    class MyGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MyGLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MyGLWidget();

        static const GLfloat vertices[];
        static const GLuint indices[];
        static const GLfloat textureVertex[];


    protected:
        void resizeGL(int w, int h) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
        void paintGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
        void initializeGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

    private:
         QOpenGLShader *m_vshader1;
         QOpenGLShader *m_fshader1;
         QOpenGLShaderProgram *m_program1;
         QOpenGLBuffer m_vbo1;
         int m_vertexAttr1;
         int m_texAttr1;
         QOpenGLTexture *_texture;

    signals:

    public slots:
    };

    #endif // MYGLWIDGET_H
```

CPP file:

```
#include "myglwidget.h"

//Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
const GLfloat  MyGLWidget::vertices[] = {
             0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // Top Right
             0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,// Bottom Right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,// Bottom Left
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f// Top Left
  };

//setup the order of vertices (indexes)
const GLuint MyGLWidget::indices[] = {  // Note that we start from 0!
       0, 3, 2,  // First Triangle
       2, 1, 0   // Second Triangle 0, 1, 2
   };


//Set up vertex for textures
const GLfloat  MyGLWidget::textureVertex[] = {

          1.0f,  1.0f,  // Top Right
          1.0f,  0.0f,// Bottom Right
          0.0f,  0.0f,// Bottom Left
          0.0f,  1.0f// Top Left
};

MyGLWidget::MyGLWidget(QWidget *parent):
  QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{

}

MyGLWidget::~MyGLWidget()
{
    // And now release all OpenGL resources.
    makeCurrent();

    delete m_vshader1;
    delete m_fshader1;
    delete _texture;
    delete m_program1;
    m_vbo1.destroy();
    doneCurrent();
}


void MyGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    m_vshader1 = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex);
    const char *vsrc1 =
            "attribute vec3 aPosition; \n"
            "attribute vec2 aTexCoord; \n"
            "varying vec2 vTexCoord; \n"
            "void main() \n"
            "{ \n"
            " gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0); \n"
            " vTexCoord = aTexCoord; \n"
            "} \n";

    bool r = m_vshader1->compileSourceCode(vsrc1);
    qDebug()<<"Compilation shader = "<<r;

    m_fshader1 = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment);
    const char *fsrc1 =
            "varying vec2 vTexCoord; \n"
            "uniform sampler2D ourTexture; \n"
            "void main() \n"
            "{ \n"
           " gl_FragColor =texture2D(ourTexture, vTexCoord); \n"
            "} \n";
    r = m_fshader1->compileSourceCode(fsrc1);
    qDebug()<<"Compilation shaders = "<<r;

    m_program1 = new QOpenGLShaderProgram;
    m_program1->addShader(m_vshader1);
    m_program1->addShader(m_fshader1);
    qDebug()<<"Link = "<<m_program1->link();

    m_vertexAttr1 = m_program1->attributeLocation("aPosition");
    qDebug()<<"Aposition index = "<<m_vertexAttr1;
    m_texAttr1 = m_program1->attributeLocation("aTexCoord");
    qDebug()<<"aTexCoord index = "<<m_texAttr1;


    // Use a vertex buffer object. Client-side pointers are old-school and should be avoided.
    m_vbo1.create();
    m_vbo1.bind();
    m_vbo1.allocate(sizeof(vertices) + sizeof(textureVertex));
    //add vertices
    m_vbo1.write(0, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    //add texture vertices
    m_vbo1.write(sizeof(vertices), textureVertex, sizeof(textureVertex));

    //texture
    QImage image("./oneframe.png");
    qDebug()<<"Image = "<<image.byteCount()<<" bytes";
    _texture = new QOpenGLTexture(QImage("./oneframe.png").mirrored());
    _texture->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::LinearMipMapLinear);
    _texture->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Linear);

    m_vbo1.release();

}

void MyGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{

}


void MyGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    m_program1->bind();
    m_program1->enableAttributeArray(m_vertexAttr1);
    m_program1->enableAttributeArray(m_texAttr1);

    m_vbo1.bind();
    m_program1->setAttributeBuffer(m_vertexAttr1, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
    m_program1->setAttributeBuffer(m_texAttr1, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(vertices), 2);


    _texture->bind();
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);

      m_vbo1.release();


    m_program1->disableAttributeArray(m_vertexAttr1);
    m_program1->disableAttributeArray(m_texAttr1);
    m_program1->release();
}
```

On the desktop I see the main window with the texture in the rectangle.

What I see when I run this program under Raspberry is only the main window  with the background color...None of the triangles is visible. The PNG file is in the same directory.

Thank you for your help.

Cristiano

Comment: Seems your vertexAttribPointers are not proper...!

Comment: Hi @Raki, can you tell me where I wrong? Why on the desktop it works if there is a mistake? Thank you

Comment: Hi @chirs,Im just throwing light into some common pit falls, have you tried with glActiveTexture and supplying proper sampler value to fragment shader ?

Comment: @raky. I've tried to cut the texture part leaving only the drawing of the rect. Same result: it works on linux desktop, it doesn't show anythin on raspy.